# how can the let the php and js interaction

Tags: javascript, php, html

my code:

```
<script>
    comform.onclick=function(){
        if(window.confirm("confirm?")){
           <?php
              //I want to write it here
           ?>
       }
     }
</script>
```

how can I do for it? or the js and php can't been together?

Comment: See: [PHP and JavaScript - What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5054171/php-and-javascript-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: Also, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757750/how-can-i-call-php-functions-by-javascript